# Head Ti S6 - Restringing options - Beginner - Tension

Tags: tennis

I have a Head Ti S6 racquet, and I love it.
I want to up my game by restring it. I am a beginner.
I am thinking of Solinco Hyper-G.

Racquet says string tension range 57LB to 62lb, while string say don't tension it more than 52LB. I am looking for something soft on my wrist and good control.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely use tension higher than 52 lbs with Solinco Hyper-G. Where did you see that it says no more than 52 lbs? While Hyper-G provides good control because of its square shape to the string, it is more of a control string, not so much on the soft and comfortable side. You can see the ratings the string was given by playtesters on the tennis warehouse site, for example: https://www.tennis-warehouse.com/learning_center/string_reviews/shg16review.html

If you're looking for both comfort and good control, I would look at a multi-filament string, such as Triax: https://www.tennis-warehouse.com/learning_center/reviews/strings/tecnifibre_triax.html?pcode=TSTX28

Also keep in mind that the Head Ti S6 is a very light racquet so it will not dampen vibration that occurs when hitting the ball as much as a heavier racquet would.